# Concept of life in exchange of life in Islam

Tags: islamic-basis, animals, life

His life was at stake, then by Allah's permission, he was saved. Now he wants to sacrifice animal to please Allah because he believes it is recommended in Islam to sacrifice a life in exchange of the favor Allah bestowed upon him saving his life. Is this something from South Asian Islamic culture or there are authentic sources where Allah/Messenger (S) prescribed so?

Comment: "he believes it is recommended in Islam to sacrifice a life in exchange of the favor Allah" Why does he believe that? Does he have an evidence from the Qur'an or Hadith?

Comment: This is a concept of "Substitutionary atonement/sacrifice", which mostly Non Muslims, believe.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind sacrificing animals(Specially a Lamb) to return a blessing that you get from God is not "*to sacrifice a life in exchange of the favor*", **It is about thanking God by helping poor people** and giving them meat(a nice and proper meal that was hard to afford).

So the main purpose of any such sacrifice in Islam is just like charity not the death of that animal or .... (I've heard even some people give the meat of sacrifice only to their own family who are not poor at all),

Any deed of such kind with a purpose other than pure charity is considered at least by me, as a cultural or self-made belief not necessarily wrong but not related to Islam.

Comment: I think there are some Jewish beliefs, relating to the burnt pass over, that, who ever does something wrong, he must sacrifice an animal to repay that sin. But, more over, in continuation to that even, what you stated as the reason is logical enough and applicable there too, I guess. But people fail to recognize this logic, and think only about "**substitute sacrifice**".

Answer (score 0):

Allah has mentioned in Quran that no soul will bear the bourdon of another. Also one person will not be asked about the deeds of another. The sacrifice done by Muslims on Eid Ul Azha is to remember the sacrifice of Prophet Abraham (PBUH) of his son that Allah accepted and replaced his son with a lamb

Comment: How is your answer related to the question? OP is asking about the validity of sacrificing animals as a form of sadaqah.